# Regex expression to match a string but exclude something at the same time

Tags: regex, string

I want to try and ask this as concisely as possible please forgive me if I'm leaving something out. I want the expression to match all cases except where an exact filename string is present.

A backup software I'm using uses regular expressions and I want to setup an exclusion to skip all of a particular file extension type, except I have certain files I need to backup so I don't want them to match.

The files I want to exclude are we'll say for this example *.FLV

```
(?i).*\.flv
```

I want to include in my backups three files: abc123.flv, ghk432.flv, and fdw917.flv

This is where I'm having trouble, even just including one file from the three to be included to backup

```
(?i).*\.flv^(?!(abc123\.flv))&
```

The expression is being added to an Exclusion List for code42 CrashPlan backup, their support unfortunately cannot assist with complex RegEx expressions.

The closest thing I can supply as an example is their Example 3: Using An Exclude To Include:

```
.*/Documents/((?!(.*\.(doc|rtf)|.*/)$).)*$
```

http://support.code42.com/Administrator/3.6_And_4.0/Configuring/Using_Include_And_Exclude_Filters

However it excludes all files within directories named "Documents" and includes any files in those folders with doc or rtf file extensions. I'm trying to create an expression working with file extensions irregardless of folder location.

In my brain logically it seems like I need to write this as some kind of if then else statement but regex is not my forte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an anchored negative look ahead with an alternation for the files you want to keep:

```
^(?i)(?!.*(abc123|ghk432|fdw917)\.flv).*\.flv
```

The negative lookahead asserts that the following input does *not* match its regex, and the pipe character means "or".

Comment: Thanks Bohemian this worked perfectly. I swore I tried this before but I'm seeing that I missed the .* (Any Char greedy) after the ?! (Negative lookahead) somehow that or the $ end of string I was adding to a nearly identical line was causing it to not work, your expression above is working for me Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the negative lookahead at the position of the filename in the path:

```
^([^/]*/)*(?!(abc123|ghk432|fdw917)\.flv$)[^/]*\.flv$
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Casimir, I tried it and it seems to not exclude anything and everything is still included. When I tried the expression on http://regex101.com/#pcre it tells me there's unescaped delimiters. Bohemian's solution matches exactly what I was attempting to do. Thanks again for trying though I really appreciate the effort, this regex stuff was begining to take a toll on my sanity heheh :)

Comment: @DA2: Try with escaped slashes (or change the delimiter in regex101). You can see an online demo here: http://regex101.com/r/fQ7aO4/1